# Update WPF Image issue under SIlverlight 4.0

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

When my page loads and I press `button1` I can get the image and can see it.

But when I click it second time  it doesn't work at all. I debugged it `button1_Click(...)` and I am sure that `imageData != null`.

I really can't figure out what's up... Please help me!

```
private void button1_Click(object button, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Guid sid = Guid.Parse("087462df-e4b6-484c-879e-cccc37b4c1f4");
    EntityQuery<Screenshot> screen = this._myDomainContext.GetScreenshotQuery(sid);
    this._myDomainContext.Load(screen).Completed += (sender, args) =>
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] imageData = (((LoadOperation<Screenshot>)sender).Entities.FirstOrDefault()).Screen;
            if (imageData != null)
            {
                BitmapImage img = Utilities.Graphics.GetImage(imageData);
                img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;

                image1.Source = null;
                image1.Source = img;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

    };
}
```

and

```
public static BitmapImage GetImage(byte[] rawImageBytes)
{
    BitmapImage imageSource = null;

    try
    {
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(rawImageBytes))
        {
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
            b.SetSource(stream);
            imageSource = b;    
        }
    }
    catch  
    {
    }

    return imageSource;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the overload of Load:

```
this._myDomainContext.Load(screen, LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, true).Completed+= ...
```

Comment: Thank you bro! Respect to you for ever and ever! It works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure on the cause if your issue, but I have a few pointers on the code with regards to using `BitmapImage`'s.

1. There is no need to set the `image1.Source` property to `null` before assigning it with an actual source.
2. Don't dispose the stream you pass to the `BitmapImage` in case the control is trying to read from it.
3. I personally make use of [`BeginInit(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.begininit.aspx), [`StreamSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.endinit.aspx) and [`EndInit(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx) when working with `BitmapImage`'s.

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for your input! @JMarsch's solution works fine for me. But I will edit the code as you've  suggested. Thank you!